# Automatic type casting of vanilla objects to Ember objects

Tags: ember.js

I'm just diving in to Ember. I'm looking for a way to pass a plain array of vanilla objects into a collection/controller and have them type cast to the correct model.

Here's the simple collection view:

```
{{#collection id="prods" contentBinding="Vix.prodsController" tagName="ul"}}
  {{content.title}}
{{/collection}}
```

Here's the model:

```
Vix.Prod = Ember.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  title: null
});
```

And the controller:

```
Vix.prodsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: []
});
```

Then let's get some JSON-formatted data from the server. In this example I'll just hard-code it:

```
var prods = [{id:"yermom1", title:"yermom 1"}, {id:"yermom2", title:"yermom 2"}]

Vix.prodsController.set('content', prods);
```

So far so good. I get my simple list of `li` elements displaying the titles as I'd expect. But when I want to update the title of one of the objects, using:

```
Vix.prodsController.objectAt(0).set('title', 'new title')
```

It complains because the object has no `set` method-- it has not been properly cast to my `Vix.Prod` Ember Object.

Using this alternative:

```
Vix.prodsController.pushObjects(prods);
```

Produces the same result. It's only if I explicitly create new model instances that I get the `get/set` goodness:

```
var prods = [Vix.Prod.create({id:"yermom1", title:"yermom 1"}), {Vix.Prod.create(id:"yermom2", title:"yermom 2"})]
```

Is there a way to automatically type cast those vanilla objects to my Vix.Prod Ember Object? If not, am I the only one that really wants something like that? In Backbone one can set the `model` property on a collection. I suppose I can create a setter on my Controller to do something similar- just wondering if there is something built-in that I'm missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No magic. I'd suggest do a loop wrapping the model.

```
var prods = [{id:"yermom1", title:"yermom 1"}, {id:"yermom2", title:"yermom 2"}];

for (var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
    prods[i] = Vix.Prod.create(prods[i]); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. When I try this I get `You should not call 'create' on a model. Instead, call 'store.createRecord' with the attributes you would like to set.`

Answer (score 1):

If I use ember as much as I hope to, I'm going to want a shortcut. So here's what I've done for now. I created a base Collection class that I use to create my Collections/Controllers:

```
Vix.Collection = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  model: null, 

  pushObject: function(obj) {
    if (this.get('model') && obj.__proto__.constructor !== this.get('model')) {
      obj = this.get('model').create(obj); 
    }    
    return this._super(obj);
  },

  pushObjects: function(objs) {
    if (this.get('model')) {
      objs = this._typecastArray(objs)
    }
    return this._super(objs);
  },

  set: function(prop, val) {
    if (prop === 'content' && this.get('model')) {
      val = this._typecastArray(val);
    }
    return this._super(prop, val);
  },

  _typecastArray: function(objs) {
    var typecasted = [];
    objs.forEach(function(obj){
      if (obj.__proto__.constructor !== this.get('model')) {
        obj = this.get('model').create(obj);
      } 
      typecasted.push(obj);
    }, this);
    return typecasted;
  }

})
```

Now when I call `pushObject`, `pushObjects`, or `.set('collection', data)`, if the collection instance has a defined `model` property and the objects being added to the collection aren't already of that type, they'll be cast. Been working good so far, but I welcome any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at ember-data: https://github.com/emberjs/data

It seems to fit your needs...

As of today, it's not yet production ready (as stated in the readme), but is quickly converging toward maturity, thanks to an active development.